# Jersey 2.21 Web.XML NoSuchMethod Error

Tags: java, rest, jersey, web.xml

I am following along a tutorial but it is an old tutorial and i am trying to follow along with new tools and new code

I am using

Weblogic 12.1.3
Jersey 2.21 (Jersey was downloaded as .zip and not through Maven)
JDK 8
Eclipse Mars

I am attaching a screenshot of the class along with project explorer. I have commented out all of the code in the class because i thought that was what was causing the error. It is not.

[image]

The code from the web.xml file is below.

[image]

The error message is below.

[image]

Can someone please explain to me why i am getting this error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java RestFull WebService: JAX-RS implementation with Jersey 2.3.1 libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225618/java-restfull-webservice-jax-rs-implementation-with-jersey-2-3-1-libraries)

Comment: I am not using Maven. I downloaded the Jersey .zip and copied all files into my lib folder manually. The other solution says to take a look at the POM file. Not sure where this or what it is but i dont think i have one in my project because i am not using Maven.

Comment: You might not be using maven but the problem is the same - you have multiple versions of JAX-RS api on your classpath.  I see you're using WebLogic - does this ship with JAX-RS and if so, what version does it use?

Comment: This does ship with Jax-rs as a deployable library. I installed the jar on the web server through the admin console and i am still recieving an error.

Comment: Now i am getting error message "Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/extension/ServiceLocatorGenerator;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy;)Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator;"

Comment: I think this answer might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361136/using-jersey-2-x-web-service-on-weblogic-12-1-1

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not the problem with using new tools. It is the issue of having two different versions of the class on your classpath. Try replacing javax.ws.rs.api from 2.X.X version to 1.X.X version.

Comment: What classpath? Where is the classpath? Where am i replacing the version of javax.ws.rs.api?